# Vertex deletion and chromatic number proof

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, coloring

Let G be a graph such that, for all vertices $a$ and $b$, $\chi(G-${$a-b$}$)=\chi(G)-2$. Prove that G is a complete graph.

I started by drawing $K_5$ which has chromatic number $\chi(K_5)=5$ and labeling the vertices $a, b, c, d,$ and $e$. When I deleted the vertices $a$ and $b$ and the edges incident with these vertices; the chromatic decreased to 3. I have a concrete example of what I'm trying to prove, I'm just not sure how to actually prove it.

To show that $G$ is a complete graph should I assume that G is not complete and prove by contradiction? Is there another approach I should take? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at it the other way around: start with a graph that's *not* complete, and try to find a pair of vertices $a,b$ such that $\chi(G-\{a,b\}) \neq \chi(G)-2$. Then, see if you can figure out how to generalize this approach to arbitrary non-complete $G$.

Comment: I constructed a non-complete graph and found a way to make this statement false, as you suggested. I believe this equality holds for a complete graph because every pair of vertices is adjacent and if you delete a vertex and the edges incident with the vertex the graph will maintain it's completeness. A non-complete graph does not have this same characteristic and that is why the equality does not hold. I am struggling to generalize and explain a proof for this. Can you give some more guidance please?

Comment: @user2553807 Here is another property of complete graphs: in any $\chi(G)$-coloring of a complete graph, every vertex gets a different color. Non-complete graphs do not have this property. How can you exploit that? (When you're working with your example, it might help to color the graph and see how the colors of the vertices you delete affect the chromatic number of the subgraph you obtain.)